# Required to update Qt .pro and Visual Studio .vcxproj on new file additions

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, qt-creator, qmake

I'm developing using Qt Creator and Visual Studio. However, if I add a new file to the project through Visual Studio the Qt `.pro` file is out of sync and does not show the new file. Additionally, if I add a new file via Qt Creator the `.vcxproj` file doesn't get updated and therefore Visual Studio is out of sync.

I am using Visual Studio on Windows and Qt Creator on Linux.

Is there a proper way to manage this type of situation or is this something I just need to keep updated manually if I want the two project files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few options:

1) Use only Qt Creator, since it runs on both windows and linux it's an good option.

2) Only use the `.pro` to add files (options/etc), basically only use `qmake` build system to modify the anything build related and after each change re-create the VS files by using `Open Qt project file (.pro)` from Qt menu in Visual Studio.

3) Use a completely different build option that can be used on all the platforms you need, for example [cmake](https://cmake.org/) is a good option and both Visual Studio and Qt Creator have support for it (i didn't used it, so i don't know how easy it's to setup, but i assume it should be relatively easy).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I will look into setting up cmake, otherwise #2 does sound like a viable option as well.

Comment: You are welcome! If it's not too much trouble, please let me know when you integrate cmake with both ide's. Also if you run into issues you can ask another question, surely someone already did that and can give you more detailed advice.